# Open vim then save and close automatically

Tags: bash, vim

Using bash is it possible to open a file in vim and then automatically save and close e.g.

```
"ZZ" | vim my.file.txt
```

obviously the above isn't going to work, but how would I do the equivalent? - I know there doesn't seem to be a use case for this - but I have one.

Comment: What is the use case? Do you just want to trigger particular `autocmd`s?

Comment: I just want to save and close as soon as I open the file

Comment: Then not opening the file in the first place would be exactly equivalent.

Comment: in most cases yes - but what if you have a hook with git that opens the commit message in vim and pulls in external info? - When i run my command i want it so pull this extra info and then save and close the vim file automatically

Comment: You could do `git commit -m '<put your extra info here>'`. But your use case is different from your question: "opening a file, inserting some stuff, saving and closing it" is *not* the same as "opening a file, saving and closing it". If you are not clear you are missing opportunities to get valuable answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following works:

```
echo :wq | vim my.file.txt
```

Answer (score 5):

See "[`:help -c`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/starting.html#-c)".  For example:

```
vim -c "wqa" my.file.txt
```